# CakePHP 3.x I need to check prefix in model if admin

Tags: variables, model, request, prefix, cakephp-3.x

I want to check if the current address is admin area IN MODEL to change conditions:

`public function beforeFind(Event $event, Query $query, ArrayObject $options, $primary) {
        debug($this->request['prefix']);
    }`

It's not working. I need only to access to request vars IN MODEL.
Thanks.

Comment: You can pass it to the model from the controller $this->Model->prefix = $this->request['prefix'];

Answer (score 0):

I resolve it by using `$_SERVER` variable. It's works good

`$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`

but I still need to add `beforefind` for each Model... while I need only general conditions for all queries... I really feel bad about the accessibility of cakephp

Comment: feel the same,really weak documentation/tuturials avaliable

Answer (score 0):

Brother you can use the class in model
use `Cake\Network\Request;`

and `Get path` if you want